# Accessing Second HTML using selenium and python to extract image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I have to extract images from the web using selenium.

I have to extract an image that is present inside second html tag. can someone help me in ways to point to image that is present in the second html tag.

sample html code.

```
<html>

    <img class = "img-responsive" src="test.png">

    <html>

    <img src = 'test1.png'>

    </html>

<html>
```

actual path looks like this :

```
html/body/div/div/div/div/div/iframe.embed-responsive-item/html/body/img
```

i have tried using `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@src]')`

It gives me all the images except the image present in the second html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the *actual path* which you have shared it is quite evident that the desired element is within an `<iframe>`, so you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *iframe to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  # other lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='embed-responsive-item']")))
  img_src = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//html/body/img"))).get_attribute("src")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try to locate the element
something like xpath depending on the index.

*el = driver.find_element_by_xpath*

> (//html)[1]//img
>
> (//html)[2]//img

then you can extract the src link/text of each image

*image = el.get_attribute("src")*